# How to reference displayed text (Parsed HTML) - Is it an object or element usable in Javascript client

Tags: javascript, object, browser, dom-events

**This is a very specific question** that relates to a broader question asked here:

[grab/copy/convert to variable: google translated text (write to other page) client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181794/grab-copy-convert-to-variable-google-translated-text-write-to-other-page-clie)

I've read DOM (wiki):

> To render a document such as an HTML page, most web browsers use an
>   internal model similar to the DOM. The nodes of every document are
>   organized in a tree structure, called the DOM tree, with topmost node
>   named "Document object". When an HTML page is rendered in browsers,
>   the browser downloads the HTML into local memory and automatically
>   parses it to display the page on screen. The DOM is also the way
>   JavaScript transmits the state of the browser in HTML pages.

It's interesting, but it doesn't state what the output is 'as an object'.

**Yet we can highlight the output**, or displayed text, and copy it, and paste it.
Therefore the highlight and copy commands must know how to access the output - ergo it must be an object **(yes/no?)**.

If these commands can access the output...... it begs the question:

**Can Javascript also access the output?**
If so.... what is it called, and what is the script path to it.

E.g. typical example:

```
var x = document.getElementById("textarea_id").value;
```

I probably need:

```
var x = path_to_parsed_output.value;
```

The answer to this question must be out there.... but I've looked at a good few reference sites, and none seem to address this issue head on.

I'm hoping for some knowledgeable people to simply state, what is perhaps an obvious answer (obvious if you have the knowledge).

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.
Yes, you can access practically anything you want, in the DOM, through JavaScript.

But there are no universal references to nodes further down the list than the root node (again, with a couple of exceptions).

You either have to traverse the DOM, using a tree-navigating algorithm, until you find what you're looking for, or you have to give your HTML node a defining characteristic and use a DOM accessing method which will either give you the single element with that attribute (`id`), or a list of nodes which have that attribute (`class`), which you have to iterate through to find what you want.

...so the trick is to find the defining characteristics of the node you want, to make accessing it as painless as possible.

DOM nodes aren't 1:1 with objects, though.
Meaning that changes you make to it as an object might not be reflected in the HTML, and vice versa (unless you're using DOM-specific methods).

In terms of what DOM objects support, read the tutorials on Mozilla Developer Network.
That's a HUGE topic, and different browsers support different things.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It seems clear that there is nothing comparable to the 'highlight command' (hence copy to...) in javascript.

Quite remarkable that something we take for granted (highlighting a page) is not accessible thru code.

Is there any other way of grabbing a full page of displayed text, for copying to another page?

Comment: You can definitely "highlight" code.  But it means listening for user-interaction, or listening to page-requests, and by hand, figuring out what the intended target of the "highlight" is, and then finding that word on the page, and then either adding it to its own HTML node, with its own CSS styling, or adding it to a new, special node, meant to highlight things (`mark`).  But again, this comes down to "how do you know what needs highlighting, why do you know it, and how do you find it?". For example, marking every "highlight me!" on the page might mean sifting through every single node...

Comment: on the page, inside of each node, searching all text for "highlight me!", and replacing "highlight me!" with "<mark>highlight me!</mark>" as a subnode, or something similar.  Or it could be as simple as having a button, and when that button gets pressed, changing the background colour of an entire paragraph... `button.onclick = function () { paragraph.style.backgroundColor = "green"; };`  There is no silver bullet, to solve it all.  But it's all possible, in differing levels of complexity.

Comment: Yes, I do accept the difficulty (in programming), to mimic the live event of choosing a paragraph of text with the mouse.

However, my question really was 
'var x = path_to_parsed_output.value;'

Comment: By this I meant:

Can we access the "displayed text" eg. innerHTML or the translated text on a web page.

By access, I mean: Can we grab ALL the displayed text, and put it into localStorage?

For translated text, there is no need to choose something..... you want everything - not traversing the dom, but simply "selectAll" and store.

Ie. Displayed text, becomes real text.

It's my fault.... I shouldn't have said highlight..... selectAll is better.

Comment: @Ace.....  Well, yes.  You can just say `var text = document.body.innerText;`.  But that's ALL text. Menus, stuff in sidebars, et cetera.  Also, for translated text, it depends on what you're using to translate... if you're talking about Google translate, it redoes the node-structure a bit, so if you DID want a specific section (a whole article, versus every piece of text in the header/menu/footer), you'd need to  make sure that the original article was self-contained enough that you're getting the title/content in the same grab.

Comment: Wow! That is simple! I've been working on: `var e = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), t = '', tagElem, nodes, cn; for( var i = 0; i < e.length; i++ ) { tagElem = e[ i ]; nodes = tagElem.childNodes; if( !/SCRIPT/i.test( tagElem.nodeName ) ) for( var j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++ ) if( ( cn = nodes[ j ] ).nodeType == 3 ) t += ' ' + cn.textContent; }`
The above script works, and so far seems ideal for: typing text into a textarea, onclick to localStorage (pg1)...... innerHTML to "<pre>", onclick the script to localStorage (pg2)...... innerHTML to "<pre>" (pg3).

Comment: The idea being, that when G-translate reads pg2 & returns it translated, I can click it & send it to pg3.
Clearly once it works, I can work on the best method to launch the functions.
Next job is to test the translation; but I'll also test your simple command.

Comment: Yes, absolutely perfect. Its not mentioned in my javascript 1.4 tome.
I googled it and saw some reticence from w3c, but these were dated articles.

Thank you for educating me..... simple is best!

Comment: As a disclaimer, I'll say that you're liable to end up with crap in there that you might not want, and which might not be ideal for, say, end-user text which you intend to plug and play into content, verbatim. Things which people do, like putting headline text 10,000 pixels to the left, replacing it with an image, et cetera, might return unexpected results, as might all kinds of other things (accessibility workarounds, for instance). But if you're using this as a tool, go for it. Also -- `textContent` will be preferred, but doesn't work on older browsers. Like I said, `!end_user;` && `!!tool;`

Comment: You're right of course, & I must bear it in mind for future developments. However, in this instance (as you remark) it's a tool, purely for extracting the translated text. At this stage, the thought of linking to a wysiwyg web design editor, is off the radar. But you're right, & it would be the natural progression, though I think it would need two monitors to gain the feedback to make it worthwhile, so it just might not be viable as a project. Text with line breaks is so compact, quick, & at a glance understandable - needs copy/paste for web page display format, but everything is a compromise.